# Django Admin form - how to show two "fieldsets" horizontally in a form?

Tags: django, django-admin

How to show two "fieldsets" horizontally in a form?

Note: I don't mean show multiple fields horizontally, but multiple **fieldsets**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each fieldset, in addition to the tuple of fields, also takes a `classes` argument which is a list of CSS classes to apply to the fieldset. You can use this in conjunction with a custom stylesheet loaded via the ModelAdmin `media` class to position things via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, but look into [Overriding Admin Templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) (specifically [change_form.html](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html) and the part that iterates through fieldsets).